# Expose Hive Table data as Odata

Tags: hive, odata, azure-hdinsight

As part of my spark Job I am storing the output to a Hive table on HDInsight. I now want to expose the data to any COTS tools that can consume Odata feed like Tableau or other such tools. I was wondering if any one has some pointers on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do if data is stored in hive.

HDInsight Spark cluster has thrift server setup that allows BI tools like Tableau/PowerBI to process data via spark.

See: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-use-bi-tools/

Comment: This one is using the ODBC as the way to connect, I am looking for a ODATA endpoint here. is that Possible? -Kiran